# Managing cookies in Perl

Tags: perl, cookies, cgi, lwp

I'm working on a Perl script that has to retrieve a file from a server. The server requires authentication that is handled internally by a different server. What I need to do to retrieve the file, is to first, POST to an authenticating server, which will return two cookies. I then need to send these cookies via a GET to the target server that has the file I need. I'm looking about the net and even here for examples, but I'm still unclear on how to go about this. Can someone show me an example of how to do this?

Comment: Make sure you accept the first most useful answer, not only to this question, but to all of the questions you have posed.

Answer (score 2):

To make an `LWP::UserAgent` object that implements cookies is as simple as this:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->cookie_jar({});
```

See this [article](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/08/20/perlandlwp.html) for more examples.

Answer (score -1):

You can certainly use Net::HTTP and look at the returned headers to pull the cookies out, then feed them back when you use write_request(), but this is hardly convenient.